# Construction of hermitian almost complex structure and invariant $(n,0)$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I'm reading a paper and it says the following:

Let $K$ be a Lie group and fix an orthonormal framing $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ with respect to a left-invariant metric. This gives a splitting
$$T^∗K = K × \mathbb R^n$$
which determines in an obvious way a hermitian almost complex structure and an invariant $(n, 0)$-form on teh cotangent bundle $T^*K$.

I see how we get the splitting of the cotangent bundle by taking the coframe, but I do not see how this immediately determines a hermitian almost complex structure and $(n,0)$-form.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: The almost complex structure is on $T^*K$? $K$ might be odd dimensional

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, on $T^*K$. I've editted to make more clear. Thanks